# niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf slower on linux server

Tags: laravel

I'm using `niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf` to generate pdf under laravel, in Windows 7 it's working great and fast but once i deploy to a server much more powerful than my machine it takes 240000ms to generate something that takes 3 sec in Windows. Is it a probleme in linux ? or do i need to enable something in apache ?
I already enabled gzip to compress the data but it's not working either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solutions:
1. You may check permission for /tmp folder. 
2. Check your HTML is compatible from which you are generating PDF